# What is locality in Graph Matching problem and Distributed models?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, matching, distributed-system

I’m a beginner in the field of Graph Matching and Parallel Computing. I read [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4587) that talks about an efficient parallel matching algorithm. They explained the importance of the locality, but I don't know it represents what? and What is good and bad locality?

> Our distributed memory parallelization (using MPI) on p processing elements (PEs or MPI processes) assigns nodes to PEs and stores all edges incident to a node locally. This can be done in a load balanced way if no node has degree exceeding m/p. The second pass of the basic algorithm from Section 2 has to exchange information on candidate edges that cross a PE boundary. In the worst case, this can involve all edges handled by a PE, i.e., we can expect better performance if we manage to keep most edges locally. In our experiments, one PE owns nodes whose numbers are a consecutive range of the input numbers. **Thus, depending on how much locality the input numbering contains we have a highly local or a highly non-local situation.**

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, locality in distributed models is basically the extent to which a global solution for a computational problem problem can be obtained from locally available data.

*Good locality* is when most nodes can construct solutions using local data, since they'll require less communication to get any missing data. *Bad locality* would be if a node spends more than desirable time fetching data, rather than finding a solution using local data.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a simple distributed computer system which comprises a collection of computers each somewhat like a desktop PC, in as much as each one has a CPU and some RAM. (These are the *nodes* mentioned in the question.) They are assembled into a distributed system by plugging them all into the same network.

Each CPU has memory-bus access (very fast) to data stored in its *local* RAM.  The same CPU's access to data in the RAM on another computer in the system will run across the network (much slower) and may require co-operation with the CPU on that other computer.

*locality* is a property of the data used in the algorithm, *local* data is on the same computer as the CPU, *non-local* data is elsewhere on the distributed system.  I trust that it is clear that parallel computations can proceed more quickly the more that each CPU has to work only with local data.  So the designers of parallel programs for distributed systems pay great attention to the placement of data often seeking to minimise the number and sizes of exchanges of data between processing elements.

Complication, unnecessary for understanding the key issues: of course on real distributed systems many of the individual CPUs are multi-core, and in some designs multiple multi-core CPUs will share the same enclosure and have approximately memory-bus-speed access to all the RAM in the same enclosure. Which makes for a node which itself is a shared-memory computer. But that's just detail and a topic for another answer.